# Why does a border increase the element's width?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` as below. Its specified width is 300px, and it has a border width of 2px.

Why does the 2px border cause the width of the `div` to be 304px? What if I want it to have a border but still be 300px wide?

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

What you have stumbled across is the foundation of the CSS box-model.

You can play with it using the `box-sizing` property which has two possible values:

1. content-box (default)
2. border-box

> **content-box**   Default. The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes only the content. Border, padding, or margin are not included
>
> **border-box**    The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin

(*source*: W3Schools.com)

By default, the border will add on to your container width/height.

See what happens when you use `border-box`:

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
</div>
```

This will ensure the width stays the same and includes the box border.

Comment: Thanks for your help,it is ok.

Answer (score 4):

As the border is around all sides of the `div`, it is present both to its left and its right. You have to count the border's width twice. So the final width of the `div` will be 300 + 2*2 = `304px`.

Comment: Thanks,so if i want keep the div with border 300px,then width must be set 296px?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the `border` to be on all 4 sides without increasing the width of the element, you can use [outline](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) instead:

```css
.test{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#A8F9C0;
    float:left;
    outline:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

You could also use an inset [box-shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp):

```css
 .test{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#A8F9C0;
    float:left;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 2px black inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The right and clean answer is `box-sizing: border-box;` Add it to your class test and your problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

> Does 2px border cause that the the width of div be 302px

No it does not. When you set the width of an element you are setting the content area of an element.

However there what you are referring to is the **outer width** i.e. width + padding + border

To understand the difference look at how the box models work here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width

And these links.

**width** : http://api.jquery.com/width/

**inner width** : http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/

**outer width** : http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/

Cheers and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

in **CSS 2** you had to wrap the div inside another (Please note that you should not set width:100% for inner element and let it expand automatically):

```js
var width=$("#test").width();
$("#result").html('Javascript says: The inner Width of element is '+width);
```

```css
#wrapper{
  width:300px;
}
#test{
  border:2px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="test">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

in **CSS 3** use box-sizing:

```css
#test{
  width:300px;
  border:2px solid #000000;
  box-sizing:boder-box;
    }
```

```html
<div id="test">&nbsp;</div>
```