# Right Div Incorrectly Aligns Left 25% of Page

Tags: html, css, css-float, box-sizing

I'm trying to center one div responsively by wrapping it between two divs - the `centerdiv` and the `sidedivs`.

The code:

```css
.overmiddlediv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
.sidedivs {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.centerdiv {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="overmiddlediv">
  <div class="sidedivs">
    <p>Left side</p>
  </div>
  <div class="centerdiv">
    <p>This is the middle and is 50%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidedivs">
    <p>Right side</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The [JSFiddle at this link shows the output](https://jsfiddle.net/v9f1qbng/) and it's incorrect, as the right side is on the left when it should be on the right of the white piece and should also be 25%.

I've played around with removing the `float:left` on the `.sidedivs` and tried an absolute position, but no success.  What's odd is that I've used this same structure of code for a footer and it worked exactly like it should - separating each piece by the required 25%-50%-25%, but on this it doesn't and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

[See this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x3945bs5/1/) where all the left elements and p tags have been removed.

Comment: you have a class that has float:left attached to both side divs so they will both go to the left

Comment: remove the `padding` or use `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` or you should adjust the 25%-50%-25% width distribution using `calc` to prevent the wrapping.

Comment: @Keith Thanks, but even if I remove those, as I put in my post, it still wraps it incorrectly.  See this fiddle for an example - https://jsfiddle.net/pe8smexz/1/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the CSS so that your percentage values aren't influenced/altered by paddings and margins:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hkq7ttvj/1/

Comment: Worked; I didn't realize that the default body has a set margin, but that's very helpful to know.  I'll have to look at what border-box does.

Comment: @wpquestionz read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129811/add-border-to-div-increase-div-width/39130170#39130170) to know more about `border-box`.

Answer (score 2):

You must set `box-sizing:border-box`: https://jsfiddle.net/v9f1qbng/1/ 
otherwise the width is added to padding size.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding from the `sidedivs` or use:

```
 * { 
   box-sizing: border-box; 
 }
```

Revised [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jepzrfpd/)

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129811/add-border-to-div-increase-div-width/39130170#39130170) to know more about `border-box`.

Or you should adjust the `25%-50%-25%` width distribution using `calc` to prevent the wrapping.